# call controller action from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to call automaticliy an action from aspx or ascx on asp.net mvc.1.0
Think like a redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at `Html.RenderAction` from the [ASP.NET MVC Futures](http://eduncan911.com/blog/html-renderaction-for-asp-net-mvc-1-0.aspx) assembly. The helper method is built in ASP.NET MVC 2.

Comment: i think i have to upgrade my project to mvc 2

Comment: i upgraded my project from mvc1 to mvc2. Jquery $(document).ready event don't fire anymore. have any idea ?